# I would like to build an executable Octave script for windows

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, octave

How can I build an executable Octave script for Windows, I don't want an standalone executable that doesn't require Octave, just an executable script that runs Octave and the script after double-click on the file.

I've tried to make a `.bat` file like this:

```
C:\(Octave full path)\bin\octave C:\(My m file full path)\pruebaoc.m
```

but I get this error:

> liboctgui-1.dll is missing

which is weird because Octave works fine on my computer, if I write those same lines manually on the CMD it works.

Comment: is this a admin privilege issue then? Have you tried launching the .bat file with admin prev?

Comment: Yes I have and i get the same error. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you install GNU Octave 4.0 you'll get a starter .bat which sets the path and some environment vars, have a look at it! And I think in the default setup it asks you to register Octave scripts (with .m ending) to be opened on double click. I guess it's fairly easy to change this to open and run it on double click

Comment: Making double-click on the m files only opens the editor, without executing anything. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, tested in Octave 4.0.0 running on Windows.

We create a sample script, along with a batch file in the same directory to start Octave and run the script:

#### myscript.m

```
x = 1:500;
y = cumsum(rand(size(x)) - 0.5);
plot(x,y)
print -dpng -r0 out.png
```

#### run_octave_script.bat

```
@echo off

set OCT_HOME=C:\Dev\Octave400
set "PATH=%OCT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"

set SCRIPTS_DIR=%~dp0
start octave-cli.exe --eval "cd(getenv('SCRIPTS_DIR')); myscript; quit;"
```

Double-click the BAT file, it should run Octave, plot the figure, and export it as a PNG image.